# Running shell script from java code and pass arguments

Tags: java, shell, runtime.exec, shell-exec

I am executing a shell script from Java program. I have implemented it using Runtime class. Below is the code I implemented

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("test.sh");
sb.append("/path to/my/text file");

final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sb.toString());
```

Here sb is string buffer object where I append my parameters and use it in exec method. But the problem is the parameter I pass "/path to/my/text file" is considered as 4 parameters

```
/path
 to
/my/text
 file
```

But if run in shell as test.sh "/path to/my/text file" which is taken as single parameter. How can I achieve the same using Java code, where I need to consider this path with spaces as single argument. Any please will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) , it's what it's designed for, to make your life easier

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("test.sh", "/path", "/my/text file");
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: Why there are 2 arguments "/path" and "/my/text file" ? Shouldn't be new ProcessBuilder("test.sh", "/path to/my/text file")

Comment: No, each parameter MUST be separated, other wise they will send to the process as a single parameter, that's why the last parameter doesn't need to be escaped in quotes

Answer (score 0):

To recreate the command you run in shell manually, `test.sh "/path to/my/text file"`, you will need to include the quotes.

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("test.sh");
sb.append(" \"/path to/my/text file\""); //notice escaped quotes
final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct you just need to add a `space (" ")` before parameters and escape the `"/" and " "` characters in the parameters