# java Runtime.exec to run shell script

Tags: java, shell, runtime.exec

I am using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() to run a shell script from Java code. The code works fine when I pass the parameter as string

```
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh test.sh")
```

Since I have to pass additional arguments which are paths with spaces, so I replaced String with String array.

```
      String[] cmd = {"sh test.sh", "/Path/to my/resource file"};
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)
```

I also tried with

```
      String[] cmd = {"sh test.sh"};
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)
```

But neither of them worked. It's throwing an exception:

```
   java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh test.sh":
   java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

Why is the same script file when passed as String worked and when used with String array is throwing exception? How can I make this work with string array as argument to `Runtime.exec()`?

Comment: You should be use the `ProcessBuilder` as mentioned in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812345/running-shell-script-from-java-code-and-pass-arguments/12812473#12812473

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First string became the command. There is no file 'sh test.sh' to be executed.

Change

```
 String[] cmd = {"sh test.sh", "/Path/to my/resource file"};
```

to

```
String[] cmd = {"sh",  "test.sh", "/Path/to my/resource file"};
```

(In general use [process builder API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html))

Comment: What will be my first string in the array if I am going to run a batch file ?

Comment: Am not sure but try using `String[] cmd = {"run",  "test.bat", "/Path/to my/resource file"};`

Comment: As far as I remember `String[] cmd = {"test.bat", "/Path/to my/resource file"};` should work.