# extracting wi-fi channel number in iwlist using java

Tags: java, linux, grep

How to execute:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep frequency | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

command in java..

```
ls= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning | grep Frequecy");
```

shows error while executing.. Please suggest, where the error is actually...

Comment: Please put the code in a code block and show the complete error log.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641173/trouble-using-runtime-getruntime-exec for answer.