# ShellScript File not executing for delete elasticsearch index

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Hi I have an elasticsearch index which needs to deleted when a new entry of that type has inserted. I was able create a shellscript file and insert data into elasticsearch with a java appliaction as below,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // Run the process
        /*Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd src/resources");*/
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh src/resources/test.sh");
        // Get the input stream
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();

        // Read script execution results
        int i;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((i = is.read()) != -1)
            sb.append((char) i);

        System.out.println(sb.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

***Test.sh***

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/pokedex
```

With my java program it was possible to insert data but I can't delete, I tried to run the above command in command-line and it worked fine. What is happening here? Why is it executing in command-line and not in my program?

Comment: May you also add return code of the shell command executed by `exec`? Maybe shell is returning error code but you are ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Java program know what "sh" is? Have you tried fully qualifying the command:

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh src/resources/test.sh");
```

What is the error when it doesn't run? Is it best practice to run a shell script in a Java program? Are there other ways of running commands in Java programs?

[java Runtime.exec to run shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833208/java-runtime-exec-to-run-shell-script)

Comment: it doesn't show any error, it simply skips that part. Yeah I have tried the fully qualified command as well. -XPUT works fine, -XDELETE command isn't working.