# How do I open a application with spaces in the name using Runtime.getRuntime().exec()?

Tags: java, macos, exec

So I am trying to make a universal app, and I am trying to make it have the ability to open applications. So, I figured out to make it open an application if it is one word, but with spaces, it never works. This is how I do it:

```
    if(textField.getText().startsWith("application open")){
    try {
        String string1 = textField.getText().substring(17, textField.getText().length());
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open /Applications/\"" + string1 + "\".app");
        textArea.append("Opening application " + string1 + "..." + newline);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

If anyone could help me out, that would be great!
Thanks in advance,
Howard Stark

Comment: Closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134486/how-to-execute-command-with-parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the version of [`exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) that takes a `String[]`:

This works for me:

```
String cmds[] = { "open", "/Applications/Font Book.app" };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);
```

Whereas this doesn't:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open /Applications/Font Book.app");
```

The latter can only use spaces to break up the command arguments, and so is parsed as the command *open*, followed by 2 arguments delimited by the space. The former - the version of `exec` that takes a `String[]` - is passed each argument individually, and so doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use a variant of exec that takes the command and arguments separately. The most direct replacement is

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"executable with spaces"})
```

exec(String[])

Answer (score 2):

@ScArcher2 is right (+1).

But this solution is not cross platform. For example you will probably have to insert `\` before spaces in Unix. 
Better solution is to use `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime.exec()`. `ProcessBuilder` creates portable command line and supports spaces automatically.

Comment: For whatever reason my answer did not work. It looks like the best way to go using Runtime is using a String[] of command line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You could try and use ProcessBuilder instead:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Use the directory(File directory) method to set the working directory (the one containing spaces), and then use start() to launch the process.

Simplified example from javadoc:

```
 ProcessBuilder pb =
   new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
 pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
 Process p = pb.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ProcessBuilder , it's what it's designed for, to make your life easier

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("open", "/Applications/\"" + string1 + "\".app");
Process p = pb.start();
```

As explained in this post [Running shell script from java code and pass arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812345/running-shell-script-from-java-code-and-pass-arguments/12812473#12812473)