# Execute shell script in Java and read Output

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell

I am executing the shell script using below method in java

```
public static void main(String ar[])
{
  //key value are being read from properties file, here I am assigning the sample values      directly

   key=mine
   value="ls-1|tail-1"


  String[] cmd = { "jj.sh" , key,value};
  Process script_exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
  script_exec.waitFor();
  if(script_exec.exitValue() != 0){
   System.out.println("Error while executing script");

  BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(script_exec.getInputStream()));

  while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
}
```

The jj.sh file contains below value

```sh
#!/bin/sh

key=$1
value=`$2` 
echo $value
```

When I execute jj.sh using key and value directly, it give me the correct value, that is, the name of file. 
However with java it is giving me the result as ls -1 result (Means java is ignoring the command after '|'). When I pass the key values  delimited with tilde sign ` then it simply displays the full key value i.e. `ls -1|tail -1`

How to execute the full command using java

Comment: How do you run `jj.sh` when you do it directly?

Comment: You might have to use the full path to the shell you expect this script to run in as the first argument; the hash-bang may not make sense to the exec shell that Java spawns. Also, you are going to have to pay close attention to how some characters are escaped, as this stuff is parsed more than one time.

Comment: The question [Running shell script from java code and pass arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12812345/17300) may be helpful to you. In particular, switch from `runtime.exec()` to `process.start()`. Also, neither is a shell; you should [invoke the shell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12833242/17300) and pass the script as an argument to it.

Comment: First, your Java code doesn't actually compile. You didn't close the `if` block. The variables I'd allow are all strings. But then, you wrote `ls-1|tail-1` without spaces and that will never fly. But then, your shell script wouldn't actually work with a pipe. You're probably running it as `jj.sh key ls -1| tail -1`, which actually runs `jj.sh key ls -1` then passes the output to `tail -1`.

Comment: @thatotherguy: I do run as sh jj.sh mine "ls -1|tail -1"

Comment: @StephenP: I have tried that also , but it did not work

Comment: @RealSkeptic: I am able to get the proper argument in the script, I have tried this by printing the $2 before it is executed.

Comment: @Jagdeep When I run that command with your script, I get "ls: invalid option -- '|'
Try `ls --help' for more information.". What do you get when you copy-paste your command? Make sure to actually copy-paste the command into a terminal, and don't run something you think is equivalent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The primary reason why this doesn't work is that `` `$2` `` is not the same as `` `ls -1 | tail -1` ``, even when `$2` is set to that string.

If your script accepts a literal string with a command to execute, you can use `eval` to do so.

I created a complete example. Please copy-paste it and verify that it works before you try applying any of it to your own code. Here's `Test.java`:

```java
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] command = { "./myscript", "key", "ls -t | tail -n 1" };
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        process.getInputStream()));
    String s;
    while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println("Script output: " + s);
    }
  }
}
```

And `myscript`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
key="$1"
value=$(eval "$2")
echo "The command  $2  evaluated to: $value"
```

Here's how we can run `myscript` separately:

```
$ ls -t | tail -n 1
Templates

$ ./myscript foo 'ls -t | tail -n 1'
The command  ls -t | tail -n 1  evaluated to: Templates
```

And here's the result of running the Java code:

```
$ javac Test.java && java Test
Script output: The command  ls -t | tail -n 1  evaluated to: Templates
```

Answer (score 0):

As other posters pointed out already, the sub-process is not started in a shell, so the she-bang is not interpreted.

I got your example to work by explicitly starting the evaluation of the second parameter in a shell in jj.sh:

```
value=`sh -c "$2"`
```

Not nice, but works.

Other option may be to start the script in a shell explicitly, emulating the sh-bang:

```
String[] cmd = { "/bin/sh", "jj.sh" , key,value};
```

Comment: It actually does run the she-bang. Try writing a shell script that only has a she-bang and a `ps $$` and running it through the (corrected form of the) above program.