# Runas will not run dns clear process java

Tags: java, cmd, ipv4, dhcp, runas

I am creating a program and i need the dns be set from static back to dhcp via a press of a button, but when i run the command under runas, and the user enters the admin password, runas tells me im suing runas improperly.

```
if(jRadioButtonDHCP.isSelected()){
   String userName = System.getProperty("user.name");
    String IPV4DHCP = "cmd /c start cmd.exe /c runas /user:" + userName + " \"netsh interface ipv4 set address name=\"Local Connection Networks\" source=dhcp\"";
    String IPV4EDHCP = "cmd /c start cmd.exe /c runas /user:" + userName + " \"netsh interface ipv4 set address name=\"ethernet\" source=dhcp\"";
    //wmic nicconfig where (IPEnabled=TRUE) call SetDNSServerSearchOrder () - run as administrator
    Process pr = null;
    try {
// Executes All String Commands

        pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(IPV4DHCP);
        pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(IPV4EDHCP);
```

Is there another way to automate a dns clearing from command prompt or can someone assist me with this method, because i cant seem to get it running. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running shell script from java code and pass arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812345/running-shell-script-from-java-code-and-pass-arguments)

Comment: @tddmonkey I've been looking over stackoverflow for awhile and I cant seem to find a thread that fits my exact problem, because when I try to run my code the runas command works, but I can only pass with a path, not a process or command.